# How to fix default popup menu using uiactivityviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have problem, my app using default uiactivityviewcontroller, but it too big on iphone 6+. How to fix it ?
[Button in my app too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU72f.png)
[Button other app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5854E.png)

My code

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: is not activity controller bro, it is uiaction sheet instead of uialertcontroller

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet= [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                             message:nil
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *actionSheetDeleteDraft = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"Delete Draft"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {
                                     NSLog(@"Delete is pressed");
                                 }];
UIAlertAction *actionSheetSaveDraft = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"Save Draft"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {
                                     NSLog(@"Save pressed");
                                 }];
UIAlertAction *actionSheetCancel = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {
                                     NSLog(@"Cancel pressed");
                                 }];

[actionSheet addAction:actionSheetDeleteDraft];
[actionSheet addAction:actionSheetSaveDraft];
[actionSheet addAction:actionSheetCancel];
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: the question related to `uiactivityviewcontroller` not `UIActivityIndicator`, can you customize your answer

Comment: Thanks Anbu, but I using MFMailComposeViewController so custom control ?

Comment: @NguyễnHoàng -- you want to change the default MFMailComposeViewController contols

Comment: MFMailComposeViewController is current i using, but button too large. I can't fix